# Xamarin Android Padding and Layout discrepancies

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm programming an Android App with Xamarin and Visual Studio.
I noticed that when it comes to padding and margin (via xaml), the layouts sometimes look very different in the designer and in the different Android versions.
For example, using paddingVertical and paddingHorizontal in an ImageButton works in the designer, but in the emulator and on my test devices it never worked, I had to use paddingLeft, paddingTop, etc. instead.
When it comes to margins - I noticed that a simple layout without having any margins specified is realized with a lot of margins on my Lollipop device, but no margins whatsoever on my Nougat device.
Is there any way to anticipate how layouts will look regardless of the Android version, and furthermore, is there any documentation on what attributes work with what Android version? The documentation for paddingVertical left me clueless why it didn't work on Devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Android fragmentation!

The default theme (which sets colors and other layout attributes) varies depending on the API level such that by default apps will be consistent, looks wise, as the Android version it is running on.

This is not to even touch on the fact that Samsung, HTC, LG, etc each add stuff on top of the "vanilla" android OS (it is open source, so anyone can modify Android anyway they like). And yes, some layout attributes are present in some versions and not in others, hence the support libraries which are meant to allow a developer to use newer features/classes on older versions of the OS. Android API reference should show you when a particular attribute was added. E.g.: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#attr_android:gravity

You can see in the above reference that the Toolbar class was added in Android API level 21 (Lollipop)

The attributes are all in the class R.attr: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr

paddingVertical, for instance, was not added until API level 26:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#paddingVertical

So if a device is on a version < API 26 (Oreo) then paddingVertical won't do anything.

Then there is the issue of the Themes. Are you viewing your layout with the same theme your app is using when working in the designer? You can select what Android version and Theme you want to display when viewing a layout in the designer:

[image: Choose Android version in designer]